# updating jagged array without losing the value in previous rows in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have following jagged array where at the beginning I initialize it as follow:

```
  double [][] Xlist = new double[][]
       {
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
       };
```

I have a counter as "count" in my while loop of code which it increase by one at each step. Now I have to update my jagged array as follow:

```
        Xlist[count] = y;   // where y is a double array that during the code is obtaien
```

for example: count =1 and y={2,4}, then in next step count=2 and y={3,2}. I expected by this method my Xlist(jagged array) to be as follow:

```
           new double[] {0,3},
         **new double[] {2,4},
           new double[] {3,2},**
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
```

but I see following result:

```
           new double[] {0,3},
         **new double[] {3,2},
           new double[] {3,2},**
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
```

in other words, the value of row 2 is same as row 3 and it is not equal to {2,4}. This the problem I have during updating my jagged array and I lose information of previous updated row.
Can any body help me to handle this issue?

This is the whole c# code:

```
      double [][] Xlist = new double[][]
       {
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
           new double[] {0,3},
       };

        int count = 1;
        while (distance > L)
        {
            int j = 1;
            while (j<=2)
            {
                ....
                ....// some codes are here

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        y[i] = y[i] + X1 * e[j-1][i];
                    }
                j = j + 1;
            }

            Xlist[count] = y;
            distance = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(Xlist[count][0] - Xlist[count - 1][0], 2) + Math.Pow(Xlist[count][1] - Xlist[count - 1][1], 2)));
            y = Xlist[count];

            count=count+1;
        }
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you could post a [mcve] rather than just isolated snippets of your code.

Comment: Show us at a minimum the loop where you are doing the manipulation of `Xlist`

Comment: Is it a requirement to use jagged arrays or are you open to changing the type of the variable that hold the data? I believe the operations would be much easier if we could switch to another type of array.

Comment: That's not the whole code. Please read [mcve] for the sort of thing we're after. We should be able to copy, paste, compile, run and see the problem - and there should be nothing in there that *isn't* required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Not necessarily, I just suggest jagged array, because I need to update the each row from initial ones and then access each row in the rest of my code. Such as: Xlist[count-1][0].

Comment: If the answer helped, accept it, please. Otherwise, feel free to tell what's missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, I'd suggest switching to another type of variable. For instance, *List>*. As it seems that you always use just a pair of the numbers, I'd even suggest declaring a type for it.

```
public class Point
{
  public double X { get; set; }
  public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use in your program something like this.

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  points.Add(new Point{ X = 0, Y = 3 };
```

In the list you have properties to insert/remove elements as you wish. Inserting a new such point on position 3, with coordinates (2,4) looks like this.

```
points.Insert(3, new Point{ X = 2, Y = 4 });
```

You can also remove a certain element or remove an element at a certain index. You can even add and remove all ranges of elements, so you don't need to do it one-by-one. The access to the elements' inner properties (the *X* and *Y* in this case) can be done in the following way to get the distance between the points

```
List<double> distances = new List<double>();
for(int i = 1; i < points.Count; i++)
{
  double x2 = Math.Pow(points[i-1].X - points[i].X, 2);
  double y2 = Math.Pow(points[i-1].Y - points[i].Y, 2);
  distances.Add(Math.Squrt(x2 + y2));
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, just one question how can I access to elements of my point. For example after I inserting in the third index, then how can I access to x=2 and also y=4. (As you can see my code, I need to calculate distance which I need the elements)

Comment: Many Thanks!! Just my problem for storing data has been solved now I am confusing about calculating euclidean distance. For example I have following points:  point 1= {x=2,y=4} and point 2={x=4,y=6} so how can I call these two points from point List (access) and then find the distance...

Comment: @HesamE There are even neater ways to resolve it codewise, if you're feeling ambitious and curious.

Comment: @HesamE I'm not sure if you wrote the last comment before or after my edit to the reply. Can you see the last code sample? It does precisely what you ask. It gives you an array of distances between the consecutive points. Is something else missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104031/discussion-between-hesam-e-and-konrad-viltersten).